# Create instance through self referential association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Am I missing something here?

*Discourse model:*

```
class Discourse < ActiveRecord::Base        
    #<Discourse id:, user_id: , sub_discourse_id: , title: , body: , deleted: , delete_date: , created_at:, updated_at: >   
    has_many :discourse_replies
    has_many :replies, through: :discourse_replies 
end
```

*DiscourseReply model:*

```
class DiscourseReply < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :discourse
    belongs_to :reply, class_name: 'Discourse' 
end
```

*console:*

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.2)
2.0.0p247 :001 > fd = Discourse.create(title: 'first', body: 'first')
 => #<Discourse id: 5, user_id: nil, sub_discourse_id: nil, title: "first", body: "first", deleted: nil, delete_date: nil, created_at: "2014-04-04 23:32:13", updated_at: "2014-04-04 23:32:13"> 
2.0.0p247 :002 > fd.discourse_replies
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []> 
2.0.0p247 :004 > fd.create_discourse_reply
NoMethodError: undefined method 'create_discourse_reply' for #<Discourse:0x00000003396450>
2.0.0p247 :004 > fd.discourse_replies.build(title: "reply to first", body: "reply to first")
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: title
```

In a nutshell, why is `create_discourse_reply` an undefined method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined has_many association for `discourse_replies` so to create a associated object you need to do

```
fd.discourse_replies.create
```

`fd.create_discourse_reply` would have been created the object if you'd have associated it with `has_one` or `belongs_to` association.